# Volume Control ValueChanged in Form_Load event & trackBar .NET Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

First off I would like to say that I am kinda new to visual studio C# (2 months in) & I've studied other languages but I know the fundimentals & the project is somewhat done, its just this one feature I cant seem to get the hang of.

So I am trying to connect a trackBar to my WinForm application which is a SoundBoard.

It is not driven by Windows Media Player it is simply just some resources (Audio Files)
It is a really boring project its really nothing special but I really cant seem to get the code to work.

(Will provide the .cs files if necessary)
What I am trying to accomplish is that I want to make a trackBar that connects to the winForm app & lets the user control the volume of the WinForm itself.

I know I need to set the min and max values according to my needs at the beginning, like in the Form_Load event.
E.g. the volume control uses percentage 0 - 100%
Then I need to set min=0, max=100.

the thing is, I have no idea how to do it, I have never seen any code that makes any sence in this scenario.

Here is the code for the trackBar, or this is what I've gotten so far. I know its not much but I am really bad with trackBars.

(Sorry for my bad english, not my native tounge.)

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
    trackBar1.Maximum = 100;

}
```

This is the code for the sounds being played with each button that is named differently.

```
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
    player.Stream = Properties.Resources.cow;
    player.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in modifying the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values within an `Scroll` event. Just set these values to `0` and `100` in designer (Properties window).

Then, you will be able to use this event and control the volume through it:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourSoundPlayer.Volume = trackBar1.Value;
}
```

As you haven't told what you use for playing a sound, I have assumed the `Volume` property. However, it may be another in your case.

Comment: Ooh! Gosh I feel stupid now, thank you so much for explaining!

Comment: Also, I am not using any windows media player module or anything like that I have just connected buttons to sounds with this code.

            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new   System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.cow;
            player.Play();

Comment: @AlexanderVarga Unfortunately, there is no volume control in native `SoundPlayer`. Please, refer to these articles: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/879973/csharp-adjust-volume-of-played-wav-file, http://www.nullskull.com/q/10096517/volume-of-wav-with-soundplayer-class.aspx, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/42b46e40-4d4a-48f8-8681-9b0167cfe781/attenuating-soundplayer-volume?forum=csharpgeneral